# Jenkins: send email from python

Tags: python, jenkins, smtp, jenkins-pipeline

How to send email utilizing python code from Jenkins job? I have SMTP configuration with Groovy-DSL "emailext", I can accomplish it; But trying to see the same with python code.

Comment: Do you have a **specific** question? It sounds to me like you need a guide/tutorial, or the documentation, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

```
import smtplib
sender = "sender@domain.com"  
receivers = "receivers@domain.com"  
message = """
Stack Overflow! 
"""

try:
   smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtp_obj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Done"
except SMTPException:
   print "error"
```

You can read this

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm